# Excel: Formula can not be entered because level of nesting used more than allowed?

Tags: excel, nested

I am trying to put together this formula, but excel for some reason is saying that it can not be entered because the level of nesting used is more than what is allowed. can someone please show me where I am going wrong and how I could re-arrange this formula to get it to work. thanks

```
=IFERROR(IF((TODAY()-BC11)>6,IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"XWS","XWW","XWO","XVV","XVS","XVO","XVH","XTO","XTA","XSW","XSV","XST","XSS","XSS","XSR","XSP","XSL","XSJ","XSH","XSG","XSF","XSE","XSD","XSC","XSB","XSA","XS5","XS2","XPO","XMO","XMF","XLS","XLP","XLO","XLL","XLB","XKT","XKR","XKO","XKH","XKE","XKD","XJS","XHO","XHL","XHF","XHA","XGO","XFT","XFO","XFC","XFA","XDO","XBS","XBO","XAO","WHO","PSO","PRO","PRM","PRE","PPT","PLO","PGW","PGV","PGT","PGS","PGR","PGP","PGH","PGF","PGE","PGB","PGA","PFP","PDC","PDB","PCP","PBO","OFD","MWW","MWC","MTT","MSP","MSO","MRM","MPP","MPO","MPF","MNO","MMW","MMS","MMP","MMI","MLO","MJO","MHH","MGO","MFO","MEE","MEB","MDO","MCO","MAT"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_PLANT2.msg","Action"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"XCT","XCO","XCA"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_CRANE2.msg","Action"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"XJO","XJS"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_OPERATOR2.msg","Action"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LTV","LTH","LSW","LMC"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_3PL2.msg","Action"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP","ACO","ARC","BCO","BCP","BFA","BFI","BFL","BFP","BHO","BPO","BSO","BTF","BTH","BTO","BTP","CMA","CME","CMF","CMH","CML","CMN","CMP","CMZ","DHA","EAA","EAP","ECC","ECC","ECE","EPM","EPO","FPA","FPB","FPC","FPD","FPE","FPF","FPH","FPI","FPJ","FPL","FPM","FPN","FPO","FPP","FPR","FPS","FPV","FPW","FSC","FUE","FUG","FUW","FWC","FWG","FWH","HPO","ICH","ICM","ICN","ICS","ITL","ITM","QMO","RSS","RTT","SFG","SLB","SLC","SLR","SLT","SMA","SMC","SMM","SMP","SMR","SSF","SSG","SSV","STA","STO","UEO","UGO","UWO","ZFO"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_PLANT2.msg","Action"),  IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"BRL","BRP","BRS"},G23)),HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\EMAIL_2.msg","Action"),
 "")))))),"No Action Needed"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not allow indefinite nesting of functions (64 nested functions is the limit - see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/nest-a-function-within-a-function-HA102809712.aspx), hence the error. I'd strongly suggest to use some helper cells or a VLOOKUP of your three-character codes and associated e-mail message texts.